# jQuery .data() assignments work in console print but produces errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

What is wrong with these jQuery `data()` assignments? When I wrap the first in a `console.log()`, it works and prints out the data.

But jsbin shows tons of errors that I can't put my finger on?

```
$("body").data("user_information", {});
$("body").data("user_information", {
    contact_info: {},
    billing_info: {}
});

console.log($("body").data("user_information").contact_info, {name: "paul", company: "testCo"});

$("body").data("user_information").contact_info, {
    name: "paul",
    company: "testCo"
};

$("body").data("user_information").billing_info, {
    name: "steve",
    company: "testCo"
};
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/exanim/2/edit)

Comment: After the `console.log`, you have syntax errors and it's very clear in JSBin. Can you tell us what are you trying to do in the fourth and fifth lines?

Comment: @Alexander in `contact_info: {},
    billing_info: {}` I'm trying to set up `contact_info` and `billing info` as empty objects. I'm sorry, the errors are not that clear to me. Can you explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to do assignment, you should do it like this:

```
$("body").data("user_information").contact_info = {
    name: "paul",
    company: "testCo"
};
```

The comma operator you were using there was confusing me.
Alternatively, you could do

```
$("body").data("user_information", {
        contact_info: {
            name: "paul",
            company: "testCo"
        }
});
```

Comment: Aha, I see. Silly commas. Thank you very much!